# "you just might be" vs "you might be just"

Tags: word-order

Can anybody explain what’s the exact difference between “you just might be” and “you might be just”?

Context:
I need to say a phrase like “you might be just drunk”, implying that the person might think of something, but their thoughts are just determined by condition they’re in

Is it the right way to say it? are there any better ways to say this?

The exact search for "you might be just drunk" returns 4 results and "you just might be drunk" returns 5, so i’m not sure if this construction even sounds right to a native

Comment: ["You might **just** be drunk"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+might+just+be+drunk%22&biw=1536&bih=743&ei=u3JKY8uFKrPE8gKHgoe4Cg&ved=0ahUKEwiLz8Hp6-H6AhUzolwKHQfBAacQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22you+might+just+be+drunk%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEMMEEKABOgoIABBHENYEELADOgUIIRCgAToICCEQFhAeEB1KBAhNGAFKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ9glYkB5g5iJoAXABeACAAckEiAHUEZIBAzUtNJgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) returns 37 000 results.

Answer (score 1):

***Just drunk*** is ambiguous, it can be misunderstood as ***only drunk** (not high as well*, for example).

*You just might be* has become [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20just%20might%20be%2C%20you%20might%20just%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20just%20might%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20might%20just%20be%3B%2Cc0) than ***you might just be***. ***Just*** likes to precede the word or phrase it intensifies or focuses on.

This ([WritingTips](https://englishwithasmile.org/2015/06/04/writing-tips-where-to-put-only-and-just-in-your-sentence/)) is not a reputable source, but it does explain the differences in meaning depending on how you place *just* and *only* in the sentence.

> Put ***just*** and ***only*** in front (of what they modify)
>
> 1. They were ***just*** *married* when they fell in love. *(not long ago)*
> 2. They were married when they ***just*** *fell* in love. *(They couldn’t help it, love was so strong that they simply fell in love.)*
> 3. They were married ***just** when they fell in love*. *(They were married at the same time that they fell in love.)*
> 4. They were married when they fell ***just** in love*. *(As you can see, this sentence has two different interpretations, because the position of ***just*** wasn’t chosen well, but also because ***just*** has different meanings anyway - **only** and **simply**.)*